# converted string failed to contain correct values of float

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am facing problem in converting float to char*.
I have written a function that will put integer part of float in string and then decimal values. I need it for two places of decimal. But something is horribly wrong. Either it ouputs integer value or just 1 place after decimal. Can someone please guide me?
Below is my attempt

```
void float_to_str(char *str, float f, char size)
{

    char pos;  // position in string

    char len;  // length of decimal part of result

    char* curr;  // temp holder for next digit

    int value, i  ;  // decimal digit(s) to convert
   float temp;
    pos = 0;  // initialize pos, just to be sure

    value = ( int )f;  // truncate the floating point number
    snprintf( curr, sizeof(curr), "%d", value);

    strncmp( str, curr, strlen( curr ) );

    // now str array has the digits before the decimal

    if (f < 0 )  // handle negative numbers
    {
        f *= -1;
        value *= -1;
    }

    len = strlen( str );  
    pos = len;  // position the pointer to the end of the integer part
    str[pos++] = '.';  // add decimal point to string

    f = f -( float ) value + 0.005;
    printf( " the value of f = %f\n", f );

        for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        {

           temp = f* 10;
            value = ( int )temp ;
            snprintf( curr, sizeof(curr),"%d", value );
            str[ pos++ ] = *curr;
        }

    str[ pos ] = '/0';
    printf("  debug --> the string is %s \n", str );  // prints only 5 instead of 6455.56 
 }

int main()
{

float test = 555564.5555;
char arr[ 40 ];
memset(arr, 0, 40 );
FloatToStringNew( arr,test, 2 );

printf( " the  float to string is %s", arr ); // OUT Put is  5 which is wrong
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `snprintf( curr, sizeof(curr), "%d", value);` :  `curr` isn't initialize. and `sizeof(curr)` is pointer size.

Comment: `strncmp( str, curr, strlen( curr ) );` typo as  `strncpy` ?

Comment: just `sprintf(str, "%.*f", size, f);`

Comment: note : `555564.5555` need `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire `float_to_string` can be reduced to (as suggested by BLUEPIXY):

```
void float_to_str(char *str, float f, char size)
{
    sprintf(str, "%.*f", size, f);
}
```

However, if you are interested in the bug in your code, it is in the for loop:

```
    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {

       temp = f* 10;  // Value of f stays the same in every iteration
        value = ( int )temp ;
        snprintf( curr, sizeof(curr),"%d", value );
        str[ pos++ ] = *curr;
    }
```

Fix:

```
    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {

        f = f * 10;  // Modify f each iteration
        value = ( int )f; 
        snprintf( curr, sizeof(curr),"%d", value );
        str[ pos++ ] = *curr;
        f = f - (int)f; // Remove the integer part 
    }
```

**Edit:**

There are a couple of other stuff in the function that needs fixing:

`strncmp` should be `strcpy`

`pos` should be of type `int` or `size_t`

`curr` should be an array instead of a pointer.

The call from main should be to `float_to_string`, not `FloatToStringNew`

The compiler helped me locate them when I compiled with warnings (I used `-Wall` in gcc).

Comment: also to let you know, due to restriction I cant use  "% .f" and thats why I am implementing this function

Comment: Yeah, there are a couple of other stuff in the function that needs fixing.

Comment: Never use `char` to hold a (buffer) size, since `char` is very small and can be signed. Sizes are not signed. Use `size_t`, or at least `unsigned char`.

Comment: @everyone, one issue I am facing .. in "for loop"  ( fix after Klas)  for float value 51.52 after 1st iteration string will have something like this 51.5  now in next iteration f = f*10  will have 52.550125  but *curr  will still hold '5' and not '2' . how would i make it to accept 2.

Comment: I've added a line to remove the integer part from `f` in each iteration.